# Http observable response parse into array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Just started with angular(version 7). I try to get a response from json-placeholder, an array of todos. That should return an array but when i console.log(typeof rsp) it shows an object.

Observable:

```
url: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

getHomeTodos() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```

Observer in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.todosService.getHomeTodos()
    .subscribe((rsp) => {
      this.homeTodos = rsp;
    });
}
```

Any ideas why the type of rsp is 'Object' but on the json-placeholder it shows it returns an array? Thanks.

Comment: Array is also an Object

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof []);`: you'll get object too. An array is an object.

Comment: So how can i use a method like splice on the object returned?

Comment: @Fishlex : sure, `(rsp: any[])`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Pranav. I think i should focus more on typescript.

Comment: Please, don't do that. Use the right overload: `return this.http.get<Array<Todo>>(this.url);`. This will get you a typed response. `any` should be avoide as much as possible. https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Comment: Ohh, i see. I'll try as much as possible to respect the good practices. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can i use a method like splice on the object returned?

I think I see what your question is. You need to specify the return type in `get` as well as `getHomeTodos` so you add type safety and the IDE can suggest methods/members on the types like splice on an array.

```
export interface IToDo { /* members here */ }
```

```
url: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
getHomeTodos():Observable<IToDo[]> {
    return this.http.get<IToDo[]>(this.url);
}
```

```
homeTodos: IToDo[];
ngOnInit() {
  this.todosService.getHomeTodos()
    .subscribe((rsp) => {
      this.homeTodos = rsp;
    });
}
```

This added type safety and now you can use `splice` or other Array prototype members.